# Trying to set the value of an input with mechanize

Tags: ruby, input, mechanize

I am trying to set an input in an html page to a certain value. Using mechanize, I am writing:

```
form.field_with(:name => 'lic_cno[0]') == "9511681"
```

but when I write just after that

```
puts form.field_with(:name => 'lic_cno[0]').value
```

I get a blank space in my console. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i'm sorry but why is have "=="

Answer (score 0):

isn't == means to test the value?
shouldn't it be

```
form.field_with(:name => 'lic_cno[0]') = "9511681"
```

Comment: I get an error when I use just one =
`webscrapper.rb:101: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end
                  form.field_with(:name => 'lic_cno[0]') = "9511681"`